# Calculations on matrix with asymptotic entries [Big oh and Little oh notation].

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, self-learning

Suppose a nonnegative sequence $h=h_n$ satisfying $h\rightarrow 0$ and $nh\rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Consider the asymptotic notation '[Big Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)' and '[small oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)'. Define

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1+O(n^{-1})&O(n^{-1})\\O(n^{-1})&h^2u+O(n^{-1}) 
\end{bmatrix},
B=
\begin{bmatrix} 
h^2u+O(n^{-1})\\O(n^{-1}) 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $u$ is a nonnegative constant.

I am stucked to show the following result

$$e_1^tA^{-1}B=h^2u+O(n^{-1})+o(h^2),$$
where $e_1=(1,0)^t$.

This problem seems to be straightforward, but it involves many asymptotic operations. I attempted to get the asymptotic terms in many ways but never succeeded.

Can you derive this result or give me some hints?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My suggestion is to write $A$ as a matrix with entries $a,b,c,d$, $B$ as a vector with entries $x,y$ and write the formula for $e^t_1A^{-1}B$. It will be a sum of products. For each product, perhaps of the form $abc$, multiply each pair of terms, for instance $ab$, and reduce with the asymptotic operations. Keep going for each product, then do the asymptotic reductions for the sums.